# Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow - inside docker

Tags: python, docker, tensorflow, keras

This is my requirements.txt file:

```
absl-py==0.10.0
astunparse==1.6.3
cachetools==4.1.1
certifi==2020.6.20
chardet==3.0.4
click==7.1.2
cmake==3.18.2.post1
dlib==19.21.0
Flask==1.1.2
gast==0.3.3
google-auth==1.21.0
google-auth-oauthlib==0.4.1
google-pasta==0.2.0
grpcio==1.31.0
h5py==2.10.0
idna==2.10
importlib-metadata==1.7.0
itsdangerous==1.1.0
Jinja2==2.11.2
Keras==2.4.3
Keras-Preprocessing==1.1.2
Markdown==3.2.2
MarkupSafe==1.1.1
numpy==1.18.5
oauthlib==3.1.0
opencv-contrib-python==4.2.0.34
opt-einsum==3.3.0
protobuf==3.13.0
pyasn1==0.4.8
pyasn1-modules==0.2.8
PyYAML==5.3.1
requests==2.24.0
requests-oauthlib==1.3.0
rsa==4.6
scipy==1.4.1
six==1.15.0
tensorboard==2.3.0
tensorboard-plugin-wit==1.7.0
tensorflow==2.3.0
tensorflow-estimator==2.3.0
termcolor==1.1.0
urllib3==1.25.10
Werkzeug==1.0.1
wrapt==1.12.1
zipp==3.1.0
```

and my docker file is :

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y python3 python3-pip sudo

RUN apt-get install -y libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev

RUN apt-get -y install cmake protobuf-compiler

RUN useradd -m rishav

RUN chown -R rishav:rishav /home/rishav/

COPY --chown=rishav . /home/rishav/app

USER rishav

RUN cd /home/rishav/app/

WORKDIR /home/rishav/app

RUN  pip3 install -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT python3 server.py
```

But then when I am trying to build docker, It gives me an error :

Collecting tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 39))
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 39)) (from versions: 0.12.1, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.1.0rc0, 1.1.0rc1, 1.1.0rc2, 1.1.0, 1.2.0rc0, 1.2.0rc1, 1.2.0rc2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.3.0rc0, 1.3.0rc1, 1.3.0rc2, 1.3.0, 1.4.0rc0, 1.4.0rc1, 1.4.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0rc0, 1.5.0rc1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0rc0, 1.6.0rc1, 1.6.0, 1.7.0rc0, 1.7.0rc1, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.8.0rc0, 1.8.0rc1, 1.8.0, 1.9.0rc0, 1.9.0rc1, 1.9.0rc2, 1.9.0, 1.10.0rc0, 1.10.0rc1, 1.10.0, 1.10.1, 1.11.0rc0, 1.11.0rc1, 1.11.0rc2, 1.11.0, 1.12.0rc0, 1.12.0rc1, 1.12.0rc2, 1.12.0, 1.12.2, 1.12.3, 1.13.0rc0, 1.13.0rc1, 1.13.0rc2, 1.13.1, 1.13.2, 1.14.0rc0, 1.14.0rc1, 1.14.0, 2.0.0a0, 2.0.0b0, 2.0.0b1)
No matching distribution found for tensorflow==2.3.0 (from -r requirements.txt (line 39))
The command '/bin/sh -c pip3 install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1

I tried reducing the version of tensorflow to 2.0.0b1 but then it doesn't support keras.
Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest refactoring your Dockerfile a bit, with the following things in mind:

- Use one of the official `python` images to have more control over which version of python you use. The `python:VERSION` images, like `python:3.8`, include python as well as build tools like `gcc`. The `python:VERSION-slim` images do not include the build tools so they are smaller.
- Clean up the `apt` cache with `rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*` to reduce the final image size. That removes a cache that is not needed in the final image.
- Do not `chown` your home directory because it already belongs to `rishav:rishav`.
- Use the `--no-cache-dir` option in `pip install` to reduce the size of the final image. This prevents `pip` from caching the downloaded packages.
- Use the exec form for `ENTRYPOINT`, because the Dockerfile reference says it is preferred.

```
FROM python:3.8

RUN apt-get update \
    && apt-get install -y \
        cmake libsm6 libxext6 libxrender-dev protobuf-compiler \
    && rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*

RUN useradd -m rishav

COPY --chown=rishav:rishav . /home/rishav/app

USER rishav

WORKDIR /home/rishav/app

RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["python3", "server.py"]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to update `pip` in your Dockerfile:

```
RUN pip3 install --upgrade pip
RUN pip3 install -r requirements.txt
```